# printing name of the link using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript.
I want to print the name of the link on the web page when the link is clicked.

My attempt is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

 <a href="#Foo" id="link1" onclick="myFunction()">Click me</a>;
 <BR>
 <a href="#Foo1" id="link2" onclick="myFunction1()">Click me1</a>
 <p id="demo"></p>
 <script>
 function myFunction() {
    var t = document.getElementById('#link1').href ;       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =t;
 }
 function myFunction1() {
    var t1 = document.getElementById('#link2').href
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t1;
 }
 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Instead of hello and hello world, I want to print the name of the link.
Please help me.

Comment: What do you mean by name?

Comment: what do you mean by name of link? name attribute or the innerHTML of link

Comment: are you using jquery?  you seem to have some jquery in here.

Comment: What would you consider to be the "name" of those links?

Comment: @DavidThomas : I mean Click me and click me1.

Comment: You want to change that text? To what? And if you want to change the text of the links *to* that text, why? That's what the text already is, so you won't see any change.

Comment: @user299662 - Check my answer. It addresses your problem.

Comment: @DavidThomas Must be too difficult for you to understand that he wants to show the text of the link in the `#demo` tag.

Comment: Please mark an answer if any of these helped solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating multiple function, you can use jquery.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('a').on('click', function(){
   $('#demo').html($(this).html());
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#Foo" id="link1" >Click me</a>;
 <BR>
 <a href="#Foo1" id="link2">Click me1</a>
 <p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: OP has not tagged jQuery. We should not use jQuery unless clarified.

Comment: When I click on the link, the link name does not get printed. Please help.

Comment: which name do you want to get ? do you want "click me" text?

Comment: that is displaying in "Run Code snippet" and check

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using jQuery, you're probably better off utilizing the jQuery event for click instead of an inline method call, to allow you to make your call 'unobtrusive' (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). Something like this:

```
<a href="#Foo" id="link1">Click me</a>
<a href="#Foo1" id="link2">Click me1</a>
<p id="demo"></p>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a').click(function(){
    $('#demo').text($(this).html());
});
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Just replace

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="hello";
```

with

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t;
```

Also avoid binding events using inline event handlers. '

```
<body>
   <a href="#Foo" id="link1">Click me</a>;
   <BR>
   <a href="#Foo1" id="link2">Click me1</a>
   <p id="demo"></p>
   <script>
      $('a').on('click', function(e) {
           e.preventDefault; // prevents the default action
           var linkText = $(this).text();

           $('#demo').text(linkText); // jQuery way
           document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = linkText; // Vanilla JS
      });
 </script>
</body>
```

Also you would be better off extracting the entire JS into a separate file and referencing instead in the script tag.

Comment: @Sushanth: Tried this but then it is not printing anything.

Comment: You need to prevent the default action.. Check the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6q7mvbuL/)

Comment: This is working fine in demo. but not when i save this andrun. Can you please tell me the reason?

Answer (score -1):

Issue #1
You are using the text, not the href attribute. 
If this is intentional, your code works as intended from what I can tell

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.getElementById('link1').innerHTML;
```

Issue #2
You are storing the value in a variable and not using the value.
*This is the more probable issue with your code.* Since the value is only used once, I would just use the value directly instead of storing it

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.getElementById('link1').href;
```

I also removed the unnecessary jquery and variable storage for a one line function

As a final note, adding return false to the end of the function will prevent the link from attempting a redirect.

Comment: I incorporated the changes suggested but it is not printing anything. have edited in code above

Comment: that's because you left the hashmark in the id string

Comment: I've updated my answer to be a bit more discriptive. The last line may prove to be important, too

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want to paint the text of anchor, please update your code to following

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.getElementById("link1").innerHTML;
 }

function myFunction1() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.getElementById("link2").innerHTML;
 }
```

**Improvement**

You can pass `this` in function call and can have 1 function

**Markup**

```
<a href="#Foo" id="link1" onclick="myFunction(this)">Click me</a>;
 <BR>
 <a href="#Foo1" id="link2" onclick="myFunction(this)">Click me1</a>
```

**Script**

```
function myFunction(element) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = element.innerHTML;
}
```

For reference - http://plnkr.co/edit/C3qN5LCpOI11jwcvx9CD?p=preview

Comment: Nothing gets printed using this.

Comment: we can suggest him for jquery as of he is new to this

Comment: @BhavinSolanki - It is working for me. If you were checking in plunker, then I was updating it so might be you referred to it in intermediate state.

Comment: @user299662 - It works fine for me. Check in plunker shared. Additionally, if it is not, then there has to be a problem somewhere else in your complete code.

Comment: I have a down vote. Can some one explain the reason?